# Glue a redondant PHP code into several functions

Tags: php, sql, filter

I've got theses PHP filters (that glue AND to an SQL select):

```
if($data->secteur){
    $requete .= " AND etude.Secteur     = '".$data->secteur."'";
}
if($data->region){
    $requete .= " AND etude.region      = '".$data->region."'";
}
if($data->ca_min){
    $requete .= " AND etude.ca          >= ".$data->ca_min."";
}
if($data->ca_max){
    $requete .= " AND etude.ca          <= ".$data->ca_max."";
}
if($data->revenus_min){
    $requete .= " AND Zone.Revenue_Zone >=".$data->revenus_min."";
}
if($data->revenus_max){
    $requete .= " AND Zone.Revenue_Zone <=".$data->revenus_max."";
}
```

I need them in several different functions , they are always strictly identical but need to be typed.... IS there any way to simply glue a "keyword" to add this filters each time i need it into any function? I dont know how to do that in a very simple way. 
For now, i'm forced to re-write them in each of my functions ! It's really ugly at the end !

I can't include them into a variable because it need to be interpreted. I javascript i would do a function like eval("varFilters");

EDIT :

I try this :

```
function filtres(){

    $filtres = "
        if($data->secteur){
        $requete .= " AND etude.Secteur     = '".$data->secteur."'";
    }
    if($data->region){
        $requete .= " AND etude.region      = '".$data->region."'";
    }
    if($data->ca_min){
        $requete .= " AND etude.ca          >= ".$data->ca_min."";
    }
    if($data->ca_max){
        $requete .= " AND etude.ca          <= ".$data->ca_max."";
    }
    if($data->revenus_min){
        $requete .= " AND Zone.Revenue_Zone >=".$data->revenus_min."";
    }
    if($data->revenus_max){
        $requete .= " AND Zone.Revenue_Zone <=".$data->revenus_max."";
    }


    ";

    return $filtres

}
```

BUt i need  to put everything on one line it's not really pratique

I plan to inject $filtres in my others functions and use eval($filtres), is it the right way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if I get you wrong, but it seems, you just have to create a function, which gets `$data` as param and builds your query string out of it.

```
function filter($data) {
    $requete = '';
    if($data->secteur){
        $requete .= " AND etude.Secteur     = '".$data->secteur."'";
    }
    if($data->region){
        $requete .= " AND etude.region      = '".$data->region."'";
    }
    if($data->ca_min){
        $requete .= " AND etude.ca          >= ".$data->ca_min."";
    }
    if($data->ca_max){
        $requete .= " AND etude.ca          <= ".$data->ca_max."";
    }
    if($data->revenus_min){
        $requete .= " AND Zone.Revenue_Zone >=".$data->revenus_min."";
    }
    if($data->revenus_max){
        $requete .= " AND Zone.Revenue_Zone <=".$data->revenus_max."";
    }
    return $requete;
}
```

to use it later, just call it with your $data var

```
$requete .= filter($data);
```

Comment: Hello, ah yes that is a nice idea , i'll try this evening thank you !

Comment: YES it is working perfectly thank you a lot !! It will change my life ! you're so good